# JavaFX Requesting focus in a custom editing cell

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, focus, tablecell

I currently have two `TableView`s in one screen, the right one has a dynamic column and the right one is static with two columns, the cells of the right table have the possibility of changing to editable doing right click on the cell and selecting the first option of the menu, my problem is I don't get that the `TextField` request the focus, I tried adding the following code but it is not working.

```
tableScroll.getFocusModel().focus(row, param);
tableScroll.requestFocus();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I add an example:

**FXML File:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.SyncrTwoTablesController">
   <children>
      <HBox AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <children>
  <TableView fx:id="tableNoScroll" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0">
    <columns>
      <TableColumn fx:id="tcName" prefWidth="75.0" text="Name" />
    </columns>
  </TableView>
            <ScrollPane fx:id="scPane" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
              <content>
                <AnchorPane>
                     <children>
              <TableView fx:id="tableScroll" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                <columns>
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
                  <TableColumn prefWidth="75.0" text="Column X" />
                </columns>
              </TableView>
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
              </content>
            </ScrollPane>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

**Main.java:**

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
           Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("syncrtwotablesGridPane.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**SyncrTwoTablesController.java:**

```
package application;
//*****************************************************************************



import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import bean.ColBean;
import bean.RowBean;
import bean.TestBean;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn.CellDataFeatures;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class SyncrTwoTablesController implements Initializable {

   @FXML
   private ScrollPane          scPane;

   @FXML
   private HBox                hBox;

   @FXML
   private TableView<RowBean> tableNoScroll;

   @FXML
   private TableView<RowBean> tableScroll;



   private TestBean            testBean;
   @FXML
   private TableColumn<RowBean, String> tcName;

   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
      System.out.println("Controller");
      initializeBean();
      fillTables();

   }

   private void fillTables() {
      tableNoScroll.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(testBean.getLstRow()));
      tableScroll.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(testBean.getLstRow()));
      tcName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<RowBean, String>("nameRow"));

      List<TableColumn<RowBean, String>> lstColums = new ArrayList<TableColumn<RowBean, String>>();
      //TableColumn<RowBean, String> col = null;
      tableScroll.getColumns().clear();
      if (testBean.getLstRow().size() > 0) {
         for(int i = 0; i < testBean.getLstRow().get(0).getLstColBean().size(); i++) {
            TableColumn<RowBean, String> col = new TableColumn<RowBean, String>("col"+ i);
            int id = i;
            col.setCellValueFactory(
                  new Callback<CellDataFeatures<RowBean, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
                     @Override
                     public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<RowBean, String> p) {
                        return p.getValue().getLstColBean().get(id) != null
                              ? p.getValue().getLstColBean().get(id).getColValue()
                              : new SimpleStringProperty("");
                     }
                  });
            col.setCellFactory(
                  new Callback<TableColumn<RowBean, String>, TableCell<RowBean, String>>() {
                     @Override
                     public TableCell<RowBean, String> call(
                           TableColumn<RowBean, String> param) {
                        EditingCell<RowBean, String> cell = new EditingCell(id);
                        cell.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                           @Override
                           public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                              addMenuMonthColumns(param, cell, id);

                           }


                        });
                        return cell;
                     }
                  });
            lstColums.add(col);
         }
         tableScroll.getColumns().addAll(lstColums);
      }
   }

   private void addMenuMonthColumns(TableColumn<RowBean, String> param, EditingCell<RowBean, String> cell, int i) {
      ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
      menu.getItems().addAll(optionOne(param, i), optionTwo());
      cell.setContextMenu(menu);

   }

   private MenuItem optionOne(TableColumn<RowBean, String> param, int i) {
      MenuItem menuPlan = new MenuItem("Option 1");
      menuPlan.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            int row = tableScroll.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            RowBean rowBean = tableScroll.getItems().get(row);
            ColBean colBean = rowBean.getLstColBean().get(i);
            colBean.setEditable(true);

            tableScroll.getFocusModel().focus(row, param);
            tableScroll.requestFocus();
            refresh(tableScroll, tableScroll.getItems());
         }
      });
      return menuPlan;
   }

   private MenuItem optionTwo() {
      MenuItem menuPlan = new MenuItem("Option 2");
      menuPlan.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
         @Override
         public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

         }
      });
      return menuPlan;
   }

   private void initializeBean() {
      ColBean colBean = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      ColBean colBean2 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      ColBean colBean3 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      ColBean colBean4 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      ColBean colBean5 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      ColBean colBean6 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"));
      List<ColBean> lstColBean = new ArrayList<ColBean>();
      lstColBean.add(colBean);
      lstColBean.add(colBean2);
      lstColBean.add(colBean3);
      lstColBean.add(colBean4);
      lstColBean.add(colBean5);
      lstColBean.add(colBean6);
      ColBean colBean7 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      ColBean colBean8 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      ColBean colBean9 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      ColBean colBean10 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      ColBean colBean11= new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      ColBean colBean12 = new ColBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"));
      List<ColBean> lstColBean2 = new ArrayList<ColBean>();
      lstColBean2.add(colBean7);
      lstColBean2.add(colBean8);
      lstColBean2.add(colBean9);
      lstColBean2.add(colBean10);
      lstColBean2.add(colBean11);
      lstColBean2.add(colBean12);
      RowBean rowBean = new RowBean(new SimpleStringProperty("hola"), lstColBean);
      RowBean rowBean2 = new RowBean(new SimpleStringProperty("adios"), lstColBean2);


      List<RowBean> lstRow = new ArrayList<RowBean>();
      lstRow.add(rowBean);
      lstRow.add(rowBean2);

      testBean = new TestBean(new SimpleStringProperty("test"), lstRow);

   }

   /**
    * Method that refresh the contains of the table.
    * 
    * @param table
    *           of type <code>TableView<T></code>
    * @param tableList
    *           of type <code>List<T></code>
    */
   public static <T> void refresh(final TableView<T> table, final List<T> tableList) {
//      table.setItems(null);
//      table.layout();
//      table.setItems(FXCollections.observableList(tableList));
     FXCollections.copy(table.getItems(), tableList);
   }


}
```

**EditingCell.java:**

```
package application;


import bean.RowBean;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class EditingCell<S, T> extends TableCell<RowBean, String> {

   private TextField textField;

   private int col;

   public EditingCell(int col) {

      this.col = col;

   }

   @Override
   public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
      super.updateItem(item, empty);

      if (empty) {
         setText(null);
         setGraphic(null);
      } else {
         if (item != null) {
            if (getTableView().getItems().get(getIndex()).getLstColBean().get(col).isEditable()) {
               if (textField == null) {
                  textField = new TextField();
               }
               textField.setText(item);
               textField.focusedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
                  @Override
                  public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, Boolean arg1, Boolean newValue) {
                     if (newValue) {
                        System.out.println("requested");
                        textField.selectAll();
                     }
                  }
               });
               setGraphic(textField);
               setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);

            } else {
               setText(item);
               setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.TEXT_ONLY);
            }
         } else {
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
         }
      }
   }

}
```

**ColBean.java:**

```
package bean;


import java.io.Serializable;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class ColBean implements Serializable {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private SimpleStringProperty colValue;

   private boolean editable = false;

   public ColBean() {

   }

   public ColBean(SimpleStringProperty colValue) {
      super();
      this.colValue = colValue;
   }

   /**
    * @return the colValue
    */
   public SimpleStringProperty getColValue() {
      return colValue;
   }

   /**
    * @param colValue the colValue to set
    */
   public void setColValue(SimpleStringProperty colValue) {
      this.colValue = colValue;
   }

   /**
    * @return the editable
    */
   public boolean isEditable() {
      return editable;
   }

   /**
    * @param editable the editable to set
    */
   public void setEditable(boolean editable) {
      this.editable = editable;
   }

}
```

**RowBean.java:**

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class RowBean implements Serializable {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long    serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private SimpleStringProperty nameRow;

   private List<ColBean>        lstColBean;

   public RowBean() {

   }

   public RowBean(SimpleStringProperty nameRow, List<ColBean> lstColBean) {
      super();
      this.nameRow = nameRow;
      this.lstColBean = lstColBean;
   }

   /**
    * @return the lstColBean
    */
   public List<ColBean> getLstColBean() {
      return lstColBean;
   }

   /**
    * @param lstColBean
    *           the lstColBean to set
    */
   public void setLstColBean(List<ColBean> lstColBean) {
      this.lstColBean = lstColBean;
   }

   /**
    * @return the nameRow
    */
   public SimpleStringProperty getNameRowProperty() {
      return nameRow;
   }

   /**
    * @param nameRow
    *           the nameRow to set
    */
   public void setNameRowProperty(SimpleStringProperty nameRow) {
      this.nameRow = nameRow;
   }

   public String getNameRow() {
      return nameRow.get();
   }

   public void setNameRow(String nameRow) {
      this.nameRow = new SimpleStringProperty(nameRow);
   }

}
```

**TestBean.java:**

```
package bean;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class TestBean implements Serializable {

   /**
    * 
    */
   private static final long    serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private SimpleStringProperty name;

   private List<RowBean>        lstRow;

   public TestBean(SimpleStringProperty name, List<RowBean> lstRow) {
      super();
      this.name = name;
      this.lstRow = lstRow;
   }

   /**
    * @return the lstRow
    */
   public List<RowBean> getLstRow() {
      return lstRow;
   }

   /**
    * @param lstRow
    *           the lstRow to set
    */
   public void setLstRow(List<RowBean> lstRow) {
      this.lstRow = lstRow;
   }

   /**
    * @return the name
    */
   public SimpleStringProperty getName() {
      return name;
   }

   /**
    * @param name
    *           the name to set
    */
   public void setName(SimpleStringProperty name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

}
```

Comment: [mcve] please! how often do you need that advise?

Comment: Sorry, I hope the post complies with the rules now, If you see any detail that It is not complies,  let me know please

Comment: Why don't you call `textField.requestFocus()` inside your cell when appropriate? Also, why not use [`TextFieldTableCell`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/cell/TextFieldTableCell.html)?.

Comment: good to have an example at last :) Now make it comply with the rules as stated: __M__ throw out everything that's unrelated (f.i. all the scroll bindings, custom css, menus and more) __C__ add everything that's needed to compile (f.i. data beans - best not the original, just use an extremely short sample bean or something contained in the jdk)  __V__ usually comes automatically if C is met and M didn't weed out the problem - but then you would know what it is :)

Comment: I have edited, I expect that it is better now.

Comment: I would call textfield.requestFocus() if my focus listener of the cell receibe any call but that is the problem, that is not the case. About the textfieldTableCell, I have inherited that class but it doesnt make any different. Did you mean that? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for example (though it's still waayyy from minimal ;) - now I understand the problem. Need to play a bit with it ..

Comment: @Slaw pin-pointed the issue: you never requestFocus on the textField.. and his question holds as well .. plus by-passing the table's editing mechanism (which I assume you are trying to do in your production code) is a bad idea. In your shoes, I would take a step back and try the separate-and-conquer-approach: f.i. there is no need for two tables if you want to solve the start-edit-by-menu-action-and-requestFocus. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

A working, but probably not the best solution, is to invoke the `requestFocus()` method directly on the TextField after it is created in the `updateItem()` method from EditingCell.

```java
@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);
// ...
                boolean focus = false;
                if (textField == null) {
                    textField = new TextField();
                    focus = true;
                }
                textField.setText(item);
// ...
                setGraphic(textField);
                setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
                if (focus) {
                    Platform.runLater(()-> textField.requestFocus());
                }
// ...
}
```

At the end you can remove the following lines you already tested:

```java
tableScroll.getFocusModel().focus(row, param);
tableScroll.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select a cell and focus on it, you have to enable selection for it like,

```
Table.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried with that, but the textfield doesn't get the focus. Thanks for your help.